# Prestashop: Can't find a specifique cart notification

Tags: notifications, prestashop, warnings, translation, cart

I'm trying to find unsuccessfully a specifique notification in the prestashop (1.7) cart.

Trying to find this to translate / edit it...:
*The quantity of "name of the product" has been reduced to the available quantity "product quantity".
*

This notification appear when:

1. I add a product at his "maximum" stock to the cart
2. Back to Admin Panel (Back Office), manually reduce the product stock quantity
3. Back to cart to refresh, in front, there is a message that I don't know where I can customize ...

Thanks in advance <3

Answer (score 0):

This may be a non-standard message because I can't find it on Github https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop

However [in this file](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/blob/6ed7395027ce33310c40a4917c457a79cfe64702/controllers/front/CartController.php#L649)
there is another message, which means that if you have more products in your cart than there are in stock, it will return an error.
Check your PrestaShop for any other message here